# Derivative of a dataset using python or pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, gradient, derivative

I have a tab-limited csv file with a dataset with 2 columns (time and value) of data of type float. I have 100s of these files from a lab equipment. An example set is shown below.

```
3.64    1.22e-11
4.14    2.44e-11
4.64    1.22e-11
5.13    2.44e-11
5.66    1.22e-11
6.17    1.22e-11
6.67    2.44e-11
7.17    2.44e-11
7.69    1.22e-11
8.20    2.44e-11
8.70    1.22e-11
9.20    2.44e-11
9.72    2.44e-11
10.22   1.22e-11
10.72   1.22e-11
11.22   1.22e-11
11.72   1.22e-11
12.22   1.22e-11
12.70   -1.95e-10
13.22   -1.57e-09
13.73   -3.04e-09
14.25   -4.39e-09
14.77   -5.73e-09
15.28   -7.02e-09
15.80   -8.26e-09
16.28   -8.61e-09
16.83   -8.70e-09
17.31   -8.76e-09
17.81   -8.80e-09
18.31   -8.83e-09
18.83   -8.91e-09
19.33   -8.98e-09
19.84   -9.02e-09
20.34   -9.05e-09
20.84   -9.06e-09
21.34   -9.07e-09
21.88   -9.08e-09
22.39   -9.08e-09
22.89   -9.09e-09
23.39   -9.09e-09
23.89   -9.09e-09
24.41   -9.09e-09
```

I want to trim the data to reset time (x,1st col to 0) when the value (y/2nd column) starts to change, and also trim after the value plateaus.

For 1st derivative, if I use NumPy.gradient, I can see where the data changes, but I couldn't find a similar function for pandas.

Any suggestions?

Added: Output (done in excel manually) will look like below where (in this case) first 18 rows and last 3 are removed. The first row is set to 0 by subtracting all values from the previous row.

```
0.00    0.000000000000
0.52    -0.000000001375
1.03    -0.000000002845
1.55    -0.000000004195
2.07    -0.000000005535
2.58    -0.000000006825
3.10    -0.000000008065
3.58    -0.000000008415
4.13    -0.000000008505
4.61    -0.000000008565
5.11    -0.000000008605
5.61    -0.000000008635
6.13    -0.000000008715
6.63    -0.000000008785
7.14    -0.000000008825
7.64    -0.000000008855
8.14    -0.000000008865
8.64    -0.000000008875
9.18    -0.000000008885
9.69    -0.000000008885
10.19   -0.000000008895
```

What I have tried is using python and pandas to differentiate and then remove where derivative is 0, but that removes data point within the output I want too.

```
dfT = df1[df1.dB != 0]
dfT = dfT[df1.dB >= 0]
dfT = dfT.dropna()
dfT = dfT.reset_index(drop=True)

dfT
```

Comment: Use [Differenciate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

Comment: could you provide sample output?

Comment: @YevGuyduy thanks for your comment. Added the sample output.

Comment: opinion: numpy and **xarray** are good for making computations on data like this. Pandas is just good at doing aggregation/filtering, not element-by-element-computation. With that said, the difference is more pronounced if you have datasets of yet more dimensions.

Comment: @creanion all the datasets are similar - they are 2 column data sets with only the length of data varying.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use what is already working aka np.gradient and put it back to your dataframe? I am not able to create your final desired output however, since it looks like you rely on more than just filtering out gradient = 0? Open to fixing it once I get a bit clearer on logic

---

```
### imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

### data
time = [3.64,4.14,4.64,5.13,5.66,6.17,6.67,7.17,7.69,8.2,8.7,9.2,9.72,10.22,10.72,11.22,11.72,12.22,12.7,13.22,13.73,14.25,14.77,15.28,15.8,16.28,16.83,17.31,17.81,18.31,18.83,19.33,19.84,20.34,20.84,21.34,21.88,22.39,22.89,23.39,23.89,24.41,21.88,22.39,22.89,23.39,23.89,24.41]
value = [0.0000000000122,0.0000000000244,0.0000000000122,0.0000000000244,0.0000000000122,0.0000000000122,0.0000000000244,0.0000000000244,0.0000000000122,0.0000000000244,0.0000000000122,0.0000000000244,0.0000000000244,0.0000000000122,0.0000000000122,0.0000000000122,0.0000000000122,0.0000000000122,-0.000000000195,-0.00000000157,-0.00000000304,-0.00000000439,-0.00000000573,-0.00000000702,-0.00000000826,-0.00000000861,-0.0000000087,-0.00000000876,-0.0000000088,-0.00000000883,-0.00000000891,-0.00000000898,-0.00000000902,-0.00000000905,-0.00000000906,-0.00000000907,-0.00000000908,-0.00000000908,-0.00000000909,-0.00000000909,-0.00000000909,-0.00000000909,-0.00000000908,-0.00000000908,-0.00000000909,-0.00000000909,-0.00000000909,-0.00000000909]

### dataframe creation
# df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', names=["time", "value"])
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':time, 'value':value})
plt.plot(df.time,df.value)
```

Outputs:

[image]

[image]

---

Next you can differentiate and as you can see within your first 18 rows you mentioned there are multiple points where gradient is greater than 0:

```
df['gradient'] = np.gradient(df.value.values)
df
plt.plot(df.time,df.gradient)
```

Outputs:

[image]

[image]

---

Next filter out non change and add new time

```
### filter data where gradient is not 0 and add new time
df_filtered = df[df.gradient != 0]
df_filtered['time_difference'] = df_filtered.time.diff().fillna(0)
df_filtered['new_time'] = df_filtered['time_difference'].cumsum()
df_filtered.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
df_filtered
```

Outputs:

[image]